# Initialising an LPSTR variable, Not working as per MSDN example

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, msdn, winhttp

I was reading through WinHttp functions and tried executing an example code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384120(v=vs.85).aspx). The first line of the code

```
LPSTR pszData = "WinHttpWriteData Example";
```

throws an error when I execute.

> Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [25]' to 'LPSTR'

I have already included the required header files and libraries of Windows and Strings.

```
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <string>
#include <strsafe.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")
```

I don't see any problem here. But why do I get an error?

When I searched for problems related to that program, people have executed the same program and it didn't throw an error for this statement or anything related to this.

Comment: use `PCSTR pszData = "WinHttpWriteData Example";`

Comment: look for [Modifying String Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx) and [`/Zc:strictStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449508.aspx)